# IFolderView::GetFocusedItem method in java

Tags: java

I am new to system programming.
I want to get the Focused folder details to perform real time processing over it.
I saw code in c++ but unable to use in java.
anybody please give some direction.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to integrate the IFolderView to a Java UI? Why not use the JFileChooser class?

Comment: Actually I am wanted to get details of currently selected folder like path of that folder,Name.

Comment: How did you integrated this control to your UI? That seems to be non-trivial in Java.

Comment: Am not sure but I have to build real time scanner which perform scanning on only selected folder/directory in java.

Comment: Are you aware, that real-time programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) is not possible on JVM? (Probably there are special JVM that can get close, like Azul's, but usually the GC can start anytime, so for real-time programming it is not recommended.) Do you mean something else?

Comment: actually i saw a real time scanner built by java but they don't let refer the code any way thanx for your help.

Comment: Could you share a link? I have only seen online/reactive applications in Java that gets close to real-time, but I guess most hardware sensors are accessed with native code when you have to react within a short amount of time. Anyway, that is another problem. Can you show how you embedded the IFolderView to your Java application? That way we could help to solve your actual problem.

Comment: I saw software in my office where I am working as intern I wanted to implement that concept they told me to make use of JNA library. This is all I have.